# Pass data between web forms inside ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, showdialog

In Winforms I Can do following

```
protected void SomeButonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ChildForm cf = new ChildForm();
cf.Grid = ParentForm.Grid
cf.ShowDialog();
//and so on
}
```

How I can accomplish something similar in ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: This unfortunately works completely different than winforms especially because you can't pass values like that. Have a look at a prebuilt popup manager

Comment: Oh god, I hate this question. And the WinForms variant too. It's like a recurring nightmare. It just keeps coming back again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this in ASP.NET. Your use of "ShowDialog" suggests to me that you will get what you want out of using [jquery](http://jquery.com) to launch a modal popup. There are several canned tools for this, like [jquery popup](http://www.owainlewis.com/blog/post/modalpop_jquery_modal_dialog_plugin/).